# Download files and subfolders in Cloud Storage with Node

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download a folder and its subfolders (and their files) from a bucket in Google Cloud Platform.

I'm using this code:

```js
export async function downloadFolder(bucketName, srcFolder) {
  const optionsGetFiles = {
    prefix: `${srcFolder}/`,
    autoPaginate: false
  };
  //Get list of files
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles(optionsGetFiles);
  const arrayDownloads = files.map(file => {
    //Get the full path (system path) to the buckets folder with fileName
    const destPath = `${path.resolve("./utils/buckets")}/${file.name}`;
    //Get the last '/'
    var index = destPath.lastIndexOf('/');
    //Get path witout fileName, to create local pathfolders
    fs.mkdirSync(destPath.slice(0, index), { recursive: true })
    const options = {
      destination: destPath,
    };

    // Check if name is not a folder
    if (file.name.charAt(file.name.length - 1) != '/') {
      try {
        console.log(`trying ${file.name}`)
        return storage.bucket(bucketName).file(file.name, optionsGetFiles).download(options).then((resolve) => {
          console.log(`File downloaded : ${file.name}`)
        },
          (rejects) => {
            console.log(`Error on file : ${file.name} | ${rejects}`)
          })
      } catch (e) {
        return false
      }
    }
  })
  await Promise.all(arrayDownloads)
  console.log(`All files downloaded`)
  return true
}
```

The code is hanging after a few files downloaded. I don't get where the error is.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: I found that files begins by `.` blocked the code. For my case, it was a `.gitkeep` inside the bucket. But I still don't know why it hang all the process.

Comment: As I can see, the issue seems similar to [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1262). Could you please file an issue at this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues)? Please include the steps to reproduce the issue and the expected behavior. Also include environmental details as node version used and the OS used to run the code.